# asignar valores de un array a otro array

Tags: c#

Tengo un array que tiene otro array dentro ejemplo:

```
array1 = ['juan', 'pedro', apellidos['perez', 'gomez']];
```

Necesito asignarle a otro array los valores del primero incluyendo los valores del array interior. Comento que los arrays no son del mismo tipo. El código es a modo de ejemplo. y el error que me da es que el índice se encuentra fuera de los índices de la matriz en las propiedades a las cuales debo asignarle el valor (**preson2[i].nombre** = person[i].nombre;)

```
//ejemplo 
public class person
{
  public int Nombre {get; set;}
  public string Apellido {get; set}
  public Telefono[] telefono {get; set}
}

public class person2
{
  public int Nombre {get; set;}
  public string Apellido {get; set}
  public Telefono[] telefono {get; set}
}

public class Telefono
{
  public int codArea {get;set;}
  public int Numero {get; set}
 
}



  public Person2[] parsePerson(Person[] person)
{
    person2[] person2 = new person2[];
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i<person.length ; i++)
    {
      preson2[i].nombre = person[i].nombre;
      preson2[i].apellido = person[i].apellido;

       for (int j = 0 ; j<array1[i].Telefono.length ; i++)
      { 
        array2[i].apellido[j] = array1[i].apellido[j];
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿"*asignarle a otro array los calores del primero*"? ¿A qué te refieres?, por favor comparte un ejemplo de la entrada que provees y de la salida que esperas.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema, que error te da?

Comment: Además de aclarar la situación, favor de colocar  el código de la clase `array`

Comment: Tu pregunta esta un poco rara, da mas detalles

Comment: Estoy recibiendo un response de un servicio donde una de sus propiedades es un array , necesito asignarle esa propiedad tipo array a otra propiedad de tipo array de mi proyecto, por ejemplo un método donde recibo por parámetro teléfonos[]  private void parsePersona(Telefonos[] ptelefonos) lo que me llegue por parámetro asignarle a otro array de tipo telefonos[] =  ptelefono[]. Pero al recorrer el array recibo por parametro y querer asignarle al otro me da error : indice fuera de rango. comento que los array no son del mismo tipo

Comment: Dices que los array no son del mismo tipo, y de que tipo son?? si son clases que has creado por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu caso no puede hacer un array como el que necesitas ya que un array es del mismo tipo de variable y tú quieres combinar int e int[].

Lo puedes trabajar mejor con List<> generas una clase que tenga una variable int y otro int[]

```
public class Ejemplo
{
  public int? Numero {get;set;}
  public int[] Arreglo {get;set;}
}
```

Y comparas Nulo si esta nulo significa que estas ocupando el otro tipo de variable

O en analizando tu problema mejor trabaja la clase y evita los arreglos.

```
public class NombrePersona
{
  public string Nombre{get;set;}
  public string ApellidoP{get;set;}
  public string ApellidoM{get;set;}
}
```

Crear una lista de ese objeto

```
var Lista = new List<NombrePersona>();
```

y para agregar usas

```
var Persona = new NombrePersona();
Persona.Nombre = "Nombre";
Persona.ApellidoP = "Apellido 1";
Persona.ApellidoM = "Apellido 2";
Lista.Add(Persona);
```

Comment: Lamentablemente no puedo hacer lo que me recomiendas, ya que el proyecto que estoy trabajando consumimos servicios y este servicio me devuelve un response donde una de sus propiedades es un array, y deseo igualar ese response a propiedades de mi proyecto

Comment: El response es un json o xml o algun tipode estos?

Comment: No entiendo como esto soluciona el problema

Answer (score 0):

Tus clases `Person` y `Person2` son iguales y eso no tiene sentido, basta con que tuvieras una sola y con eso se soluciona tu problema. Voy a suponer que son clases de ejemplo y que en la "realidad" son distintas.

Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
public Person2[] parsePerson(Person[] person)
{
    List<Person2> person2List = new List<Person2>();

    foreach(var p in person) 
    {
        Person2 p2 = new Person2();
        p2.Nombre=p.Nombre;
        p2.Apellido=p.Apellido;
        p2.telefono=p.telefono;
        person2List.Add(p2);
    }
    return person2List.ToArray();
}
```

En este caso para los teléfonos hacemos simplemente `p2.telefono=p.telefono;`, de esta manera igualamos por referencia, esto quiere decir que si luego haces un cambio en el objeto `Person` se verá reflejado automáticamente en `Person2`. En palabras simples: Si No vas hacer ningún cambio en el objeto de origen (person) esta es la forma que te sirve. Si vas a hacer cambios y quieres que también se vean reflejados en el objeto destino (person2) también es la manera que te sirve. Caso contrario deberás hacer lo siguiente:

```
public Person2[] parsePerson(Person[] person)
{
    List<Person2> person2List = new List<Person2>();

    foreach(var p in person) 
    {
        Person2 p2 = new Person2();
        p2.Nombre=p.Nombre;
        p2.Apellido=p.Apellido;
        List<Telefono> fonos = new List<Telefono>();
        foreach(var t in p.telefono)
        {
            fonos.Add(new Telefono()
            {
                Numero=t.Numero,
                codArea=t.codArea
            });
        }
        p2.telefono=fonos.ToArray();
        person2List.Add(p2);
    }
    return person2List.ToArray();
}
```